# Randomly apply Keras `PreprocessingLayer`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

[Imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) has a `p` parameter which defines a probability for how often a certain augmentation is applied e.g. in 50% of the inputs. Is there something similar for the Keras  `PreprocessingLayer`s? One example of such a layer is the `RandomFlip`. In `imgaug` we can say that this function should be activated with a probability `p`, but I guess that the Keras implementation assumes that 50% of the images are to be flipped.

The current implementations of the `PreprocessingLayer`s  used for augmentation have the following structure:

If `training==True` apply `function`. Else pass input forward.

```
def call(self,inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
      if training is None:
          training = K.learning_phase()
      def function():
          return do_something(input)

      # comparable to K.switch(condition,true_function,else_function)
      output = control_flow_util.smart_cond(training,function,lambda: inputs)
      return output
```

I could implement the random apply behavior by changing

```
    if training is None:
          training = K.learning_phase()
```

to something like

```
    if training is None:
          training = K.learning_phase()
          # most likely 'K.switch' or 'tf.cond' must be used instead of 'if' (but 'if' is more readable) 
          if training:
              training = uniform(0,1)<self.p
```

But I think this should be part of every `RandomFunction` layer. So I am asking here, does a parameter `p` already exist for the preprocessing layers? Or should I open an issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another note about KerasCV -- it also offers [`keras_cv.layers.MaybeApply`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv/blob/master/keras_cv/layers/preprocessing/maybe_apply.py), which does exactly what @Innat's answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is **no such probability** parameter to control the occurrence of the keras built-in [augmentation layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/). What we can do is create a custom layer to wrap the built-in augmentation layers and make it a random choice in action.

```
class RandomChance(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, layer, probability, **kwargs):
        super(RandomChance, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layer = layer
        self.probability = probability

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        apply_layer = tf.random.uniform([]) < self.probability
        outputs = tf.cond(
            pred=tf.logical_and(apply_layer, training),
            true_fn=lambda: self.layer(inputs),
            false_fn=lambda: inputs,
        )
        return outputs

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update(
            {
                "layer": tf.keras.layers.serialize(self.layer),
                "probability": self.probability,
            }
        )
        return config
```

Now, you can do

```
random_aug = keras.Sequential(
    [
        RandomChance(layers.RandomFlip(), 0.75),
        RandomChance(layers.RandomBrightness(factor=0.2), 0.5),
    ]
)
```

---

FYI, you may not need to do the above approach in the future. From [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) 2.9, you can use [`KerasCV`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv), which offers many augmentations and each contains a `rate` parameter to control the occurrence of the augmentation layer. An interesting note, most of the augmentations are batch vectorized and should run faster than existing augmentation libraries.